# Why does the inner div not expand to the set height/min-height?

Tags: css

Why does `height: 100%` have no effect on `#baz` in the following code? How could you fix this when `min-height` on (some of) the ancestor element(s) is required?

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="baz">
            foo bar baz
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { border: 3px solid red; padding: 5px; }
#foo { height: 300px; }
#bar { min-height: 100%; }
#baz { height: 100%; }
```

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/pmmyP/

Tested with Chrome 12 and Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following kind of works:

```
#bar { min-height: 100%; position: relative; }
#baz { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
```

But is there another (or better) way?

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/pmmyP/1/

Comment: That seems to ignore any margins you've specified though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `min-height` when you want `height`
**min-height means it can't go smaller.** `height: 100%` means 100% of the parent element's height *(which isn't specified and so it defaults to `auto` I think)*.

```
#bar, #baz { height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

The `box-sizing` is so that they stay inside each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zweu7/1/

Explanation of min-height: http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/height-and-min-height/

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, nor a valid solution. `min-height` on bar works, but then `height: 100%` on baz does not. Why is the question? As I said: `min-height` on (some of) the ancestor element(s) is required. And I thought "min(imal)" means "at least", thus `min-height` means at least the specified height.

Comment: @Qtax ah i see the change. But then the real question is why is it required? put both `min-height` and `height` on it if it is really needed. It doesn't work because `height` is not set.

Comment: @Qtax I believe that `height: 100%` looks at the parent `height` (which is unspecified and so it is `auto`) and says that it must be the height of the content.

Comment: That seems like a bug to me. How would you make baz full height when the parent has a `min-height`?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the w3c algorthim: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights So the question still stands: Why `min-height`?

Comment: @Qtax you should read this: http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/height-and-min-height/  Explains it better than I ever could. (IMHO)